# Accessing elements parent style XAML Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

For example, i have the following Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MyType">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyType">
          <Grid>
             <Button x:Name="MyButton"/>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Is it possible to inherit from him a different style and change the properties of the button "MyButton"? For example change the property Visibility?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way of achieving this.

1. Use `BasedOn`

   ```
   <Style TargetType="MyChildType" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}" >
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyType">
             <Grid>
               <Button x:Name="MyButton" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
             </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
   ```
2. Apply style to MyButton and put Trigger in Style.Triggers to change the properties of button depending on the properties of parent